# Can not access array elements after transferring the array from Device to Host in CUDA

Tags: arrays, cuda

I set up CUDA 6.5 and I'm just trying to run a very basic code.

What I'm trying to do is to copy an array from host to device and then copy it back from device to host.

```
int *d_mandelbrot_set;
int a[5] = {1,2,3,4,5};
cudaError_t cudaStatus;


// Allocate GPU buffers for three vectors (two input, one output)    .
cudaStatus = cudaMalloc((void**)&d_mandelbrot_set, 5 * sizeof(int));

if (cudaStatus == cudaSuccess) cout << "Success\n";
cudaStatus = cudaMemcpy(d_mandelbrot_set, a, 5 * sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice); 
if (cudaStatus == cudaSuccess) cout << "Success\n";

int *h_mandelbrot_set;
cudaStatus = cudaMemcpy(h_mandelbrot_set, d_mandelbrot_set, 5*sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
if (cudaStatus == cudaSuccess) cout << "Success\n";

for (int k = 0; k < 5; k++)
    cout << h_mandelbrot_set[k] << " ";     // THIS IS WHAT GIVES THE RUN TIME ERROR
```

But when I try to access elements in `h_mandelbrot_set` array, it gives a run time error.

Comment: You've not allocated `h_mandelbrot_set`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you only defined a pointer (`int *h_mandelbrot_set;`). Before, calling last cudaMemcpy, you need to allocated memory for this pointer. The following code will work. However, in general, you may like to allocate memory dynamically.

```
int *d_mandelbrot_set;
int a[5] = {1,2,3,4,5};
cudaError_t cudaStatus;


// Allocate GPU buffers for three vectors (two input, one output)    .
cudaStatus = cudaMalloc((void**)&d_mandelbrot_set, 5 * sizeof(int));

if (cudaStatus == cudaSuccess) cout << "Success\n";
cudaStatus = cudaMemcpy(d_mandelbrot_set, a, 5 * sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice); 
if (cudaStatus == cudaSuccess) cout << "Success\n";

int h_mandelbrot_set[5];
cudaStatus = cudaMemcpy(&h_mandelbrot_set, d_mandelbrot_set, 5*sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
if (cudaStatus == cudaSuccess) cout << "Success\n";

for (int k = 0; k < 5; k++)
    cout << h_mandelbrot_set[k] << " ";     // THIS IS WHAT GIVES THE RUN TIME ERROR
```